# fxml file loaded but doesnt show

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a minigame where the tiles on the screen will turn blue in a certain order one-by-one and after that is done, the player is required to tap on the tiles in the same order. The problem is even after my "view/Follow.fxml" is loaded, it will the program will remain on "view/SplashScreen.fxml" and wait for the arraylist to be filled up. When it finally shows "view.Follow.fxml", the tiles all turn blue at the same time.

So why does "view/Follow.fxml" not show before the arraylist is filled?

MainApp.java:

public class MainApp extends Application {

```
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
public String game;

public static ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
private int step = 0;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public MainApp() {
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Brainy");

    initRootLayout();

    showScreen("view/DefaultScreen.fxml");
}

/**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the screen inside the root layout.
 */
public void showScreen(String s){
    try {
        System.out.println(s);
        // Load default screen.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(s));
        AnchorPane screen = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set default screen into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(screen);

        switch(s){
        case "view/DefaultScreen.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            DefaultScreenController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
            break;
        case "view/Training.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            System.out.println(loader.getController());
            TrainingController controller1 = loader.getController();
            controller1.setMainApp(this);
            controller1.update(step);
            break;
        case "view/Performance.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            PerformanceController controller2 = loader.getController();
            controller2.setMainApp(this);
            controller2.update();
            break;
        case "view/StudyScreen.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            //DefaultScreenController controller = loader.getController();
            //controller.setMainApp(this);
            break;    
        case "view/GamesScreen.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            GamesScreenController controller4 = loader.getController();
            controller4.setMainApp(this);
            break;   
        case "view/SplashScreen.fxml" :
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            SplashScreenController controller5 = loader.getController();
            controller5.setMainApp(this);
            controller5.update(game);
            String next = "";
            switch(game){
                case "Brevity":
                        next = "view/Brevity.fxml";
                        break;
                case "Follow The Leader":
                        next = "view/Follow.fxml";
                        break;
                case "Operations":
                        next = "view/Operations.fxml";
                        //next = "view/DefaultScreen.fxml";
                        break;
                }
            splash(next);
            break;  
            case "view/Brevity.fxml" :
                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                BrevityController controller6 = loader.getController();
                controller6.setMainApp(this);
                controller6.update(0);
                break; 
            case "view/Follow.fxml" :
                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                FollowController controller7 = loader.getController();
                controller7.setMainApp(this);
                controller7.update();
                break; 
            case "view/Operations.fxml":
                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                //System.out.println((boolean)loader.getController());
                OperationsController controller8 = loader.getController();
                controller8.setMainApp(this);
                controller8.update(0);
                break;
            case "view/GameOver.fxml":
                GameOverController controller9 = loader.getController();
                controller9.setMainApp(this);
                controller9.update();
                break;
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public void splash(String s) throws Exception {
    final Task questionTask = new Task<Void>() { 
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
            for(int i=0;i<questions.size();++i){
                Thread.sleep(200);
                updateProgress(i+1,questions.size());
                updateMessage("Generating questions... "+i+"/"+questions.size());
            }
            Thread.sleep(200);
            updateMessage("Starting game.");
            return null;
        }
    };
    showSplash(questionTask,() -> showMainStage(s));
    new Thread(questionTask).start();
}

private void showMainStage(String s) {
    showScreen(s);
}

private void showSplash(Task<?> task,InitCompletionHandler initCompletionHandler) {
    SplashScreenController.progressTextProperty.bind(task.messageProperty());
    SplashScreenController.loadProgressProperty.bind(task.progressProperty());
    task.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            SplashScreenController.loadProgressProperty.unbind();
            SplashScreenController.loadProgressProperty.set(1);
            primaryStage.toFront();

            initCompletionHandler.complete();
        } // todo add code to gracefully handle other task states.
    });
    final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
    primaryStage.show();
}

public interface InitCompletionHandler {
    public void complete();
}

public void setStep(int i){
    step+=i;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

FollowController.java:

public class FollowController {

```
@FXML
private Label score;
@FXML
private Label time;
@FXML
private Rectangle r1;
@FXML
private Rectangle r2;
@FXML
private Rectangle r3;
@FXML
private Rectangle r4;
@FXML
private Rectangle r5;
@FXML
private Rectangle r6;
@FXML
private Rectangle r7;
@FXML
private Rectangle r8;
@FXML
private Rectangle r9;

private int timerInt, temp = 0;
private ArrayList<Rectangle> rect = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> tiles;
private int scoreInt = 0;
private Stage stage;
private MainApp mainApp;

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    rect.add(r1);
    rect.add(r2);
    rect.add(r3);
    rect.add(r4);
    rect.add(r5);
    rect.add(r6);
    rect.add(r7);
    rect.add(r8);
    rect.add(r9);
}
public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;
}


public void update() throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i=0;i<rect.size();++i){
        rect.get(i).setFill(null);
    }       
    timerInt = 120;
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
        public void handle(long l){
            temp++;
            if(temp%60 == 0) 
                timerInt--;

            if(timerInt == 0){
                this.stop();
                mainApp.showScreen("view/GameOver.fxml");
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();    
    updatePattern();
}

public void updatePattern() throws InterruptedException{
    Random r = new Random();
    int difficulty = r.nextInt(6)+3;
    tiles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<difficulty;++i){
        int tile = r.nextInt(9)+1;
        //check for overlapping
        if(i!=0){
            for(int j = 0; j<tiles.size(); j++){ 
                while(tile==tiles.get(j)){
                    tile = r.nextInt(9);
                    j=0;
                }
            }
        }
        tiles.add((Integer)tile);
        System.out.println("thread tiles "+tiles);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    setRect(tiles);
}

public void setRect(ArrayList<Integer> list) throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
          rect.get(list.get(i)).setFill(Color.BLUE);
          Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
public void correct(){
    scoreInt+=1;
    score.setText(Integer.toString(scoreInt));
}

public void checkCorrect(int tile, int i){
    if(tile==i)
        correct();
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.  Also, you forgot to debug.

Comment: @Paul Hicks What debug?

Comment: A debugger.  Can you tell use what's working, what's not working, and what you're seeing that you don't expecct to see?